# How to resolve '1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found' in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, arguments, state-management

I'm working on a Flutter application and encountered an error with the `TomatoIcon` widget, which expects 1 positional argument. I'm not sure what argument I need to pass to it. Here's the context of how I'm using the `TomatoIcon` widget within a `SingleChildScrollView`.

```dart
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(height: 40, child: HelloUser()),
      SizedBox(height: 68, child: ChipsBlog()),
      SizedBox(height: 80, child: TomatoIcon()), // Error occurs here
      SizedBox(height: 77, child: HomePageTimerUI()),
      SizedBox(height: 580, child: StartPomodoro()),
      SizedBox(height: 580, child: ToDoPage()),
      SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, child: FooterPomoworko()),
    ],
  ),
),
```

And here is the `TomatoIcon` class defined in `tomato.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../open_source/controllers/countdown_controller.dart';

class TomatoIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  final Rx<stateRound> state;
  const TomatoIcon(this.state, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TomatoIcon> createState() => _TomatoIconState();
}

class _TomatoIconState extends State<TomatoIcon> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () => IconButton(
          onPressed: null,
          icon: widget.state.value == stateRound.done
              ? Image.asset('assets/icons/tomatoDone.png')
              : Image.asset('assets/icons/tomatoUndone.png')),
    );
  }
}
```

The error I'm facing is:

```
1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. Try adding
 the missing arguments.
```

This error occurs when I try to instantiate `TomatoIcon` without any arguments, but based on the class definition, it expects a `state` parameter of type `Rx<stateRound>`.

I've tried looking for similar issues on Stack Overflow but couldn't find anything that addresses this specific problem. How should I properly instantiate the `TomatoIcon` widget? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TomatoIcon` constructor reads

```dart
final Rx<stateRound> state;
const TomatoIcon(this.state, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

so you have to provide `TomatoIcon` with a `Rx<stateRound>`, like so:

```dart
SizedBox(height: 80, child:  TomatoIcon(myRx)), // here you provide TomatoIcon with its positional argument
```

More on this topic here:

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters

Comment: Throws me this error: `Undefined name 'myRx'.`

Comment: `myRx` is an example name for an instance of the `Rx<stateRound>` class.